# I Cannot Change Background Color of Fragment in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, background-color

I want to change the background color of a fragment. But when I click on the button nothing happens.

In my main activity layout XML file I imported the fragment.

Here is my code:

```
public class Top_Fragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {
    Button button;
    LinearLayout mLinearLayout;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.top_fragment, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        button = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.button);
        mLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.layout);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        mLinearLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffbb33"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your xml code and activity code also

Comment: Instead of putting silly questions here. First, Learn android basics properly. [Check here](http://www.androidhive.info/)

Comment: Did you `setOnClickListener` for button? Another question,Is the Button in Fragment or Activity layout? If Activity , Why not do this in Activity and if another you should use `fragmentView.findViewById` instead of `getActivity().findViewById` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.top_fragment,container, false);

}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    button = (Button)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.button);
    mLinearLayout = (LinearLayout)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.layout);
}
```

with

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View fragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.top_fragment,container, false)

    button = (Button)fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(this);
    mLinearLayout = (LinearLayout)fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.layout);

    return fragmentView;

}
```

Comment: still Not Working

Comment: @GugaRai updated answer, i was assuming you were setting an onClick listener but its possible you are not

Comment: When i paste this code mLinearLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffbb33")); inside onCreateView its work well but when i paste inside onClick it is not working

Comment: That is because you are not setting the onClickListener for the button, this is very basic stuff , i suggest do a little more reading before carrying on

Comment: i know about how onClick work but i dont have much experience/practise  in them   can  you tell me  where is my fault

Comment: Its hard to debug without seeing the full fragment + activity code

Comment: here is the code             https://www.evernote.com/shard/s365/sh/53b901ef-c28e-4c36-9b03-0ba22f660176/9c53e0c3b3a6cc44eec24f397710f22d

Answer (score 1):

Your code is perfectly but you need to add button.setOnClickListener(this);

```
     @Override
     public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

     button = (Button)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.button);
     mLinearLayout = (LinearLayout)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.layout);
     button.setOnClickListener(this); }
```

Comment: the below answer is working yeah i also i forgot to add button.setOnClickListener(this);  but i incluce view base a base class of linearlayout to work my code so the below a man gave me answer check out below answer